# How to add to a variable inside of a function?

Tags: python, python-3.6

I'm making a sort of text based RPG for fun and I'm having some trouble adding to the "balance" variable to give the player more money.

```
balance = int(0)

def step_result(balance):
    result = random.randint(1,5)
    if result == 1:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print("You come across a friendly merchant who gives you 50 gold pieces as a token of friendship")
        balance = balance + 50
        time.sleep(1)
```

Later on in the code, I use print(balance) to show the balance but it still displays as 0. Any ideas?

Comment: You're passing the `balance` as an argument. It should be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, global should fix your issue

```
balance = int(0)

def step_result(balance):
    result = random.randint(1,5)
    global balance
    if result == 1:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print("You come across a friendly merchant who gives you 50 gold pieces as a token of friendship")
        balance = balance + 50
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: you're welcome, if you want you can confirm my answer. Thanks!